# How can I edit the JSON of a file in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, file, object

I looked around and found the functions `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`, and tried to make a basic code to change the `Name` of `[0]['Face']` in my code to 'Testing Face', but it overwrites the JSON entirely.

This is my JSON prior to the PHP code:

```
[{"Hat":{"Name":"Stylin' Shades","Id":"221177193"},{"Gear":{"Name":"Red Sparkle Time Claymore", "Id":"221181437"}}, {"Face":{"Name":"Joyful Smile", "Id":"209995366"}]
```

It should be changing to

```
[{"Hat":{"Name":"Stylin' Shades","Id":"221177193"},{"Gear":{"Name":"Red Sparkle Time Claymore", "Id":"221181437"}}, {"Face":{"Name":"Testing Face", "Id":"209995366"}]
```

But instead, the entire JSON is replaced with `[{"Face":{"Name":"No"}}]`

My PHP:

```
<?php
$file = 'notifier.json';
$jsonString = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
$data[0]['Face']['Name'] = 'Testing Face';
$newJSON = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents($file, $newJSON);
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON has a syntax error. Specifically this:

```
...,{"Gear":{"Name":"Red Sparkle Time Claymore", "Id":"221181437"}}, {"...
```

You have to remove the first pair of curly braces enclosing `"Gear"`. The last `{` doesn't have a `}` friend.

Fixed JSON:

```
[{"Hat":{"Name":"Stylin' Shades","Id":"221177193"},"Gear":{"Name":"Red Sparkle Time Claymore", "Id":"221181437"}, "Face":{"Name":"Joyful Smile", "Id":"209995366"}}]
```

Next, you need to convert the returned objects into associative arrays using the second argument of `json_decode`:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). (See `$assoc` argument.)

Answer (score 1):

Add the second param to `json_deconde` to true (When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. )

Read More in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php
$file = 'notifier.json';
$jsonString = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$data[0]['Face']['Name'] = 'Testing Face';

$newJSON = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents($file, $newJSON);
?>
```

Comment: He converted `stdClass` to `array` in json_decode, which fixes my problem. Thanks!

Comment: He set the optional parameter in `json_decode()` that determines all objects should be decoded as associative arrays instead. It allows `$data[0]['Face']['Name']` to work. However, it is not necessary, you could simply use `$data[0]->Face->Name = 'Testing Face'` instead (that also looks cleaner imo). But this isnt the issue, theres an error with the AJAX, thats why its not being decoded to begin with.